# Perl rsync using expect (rsync in daemon mode)

Tags: perl, expect, rsync

I'm attempting to write a perl routine that's uses expect to automate my rysnc commands.  Rsync is in daemon mode, hence the "::".  I believe based on the output of expect that my command is properly formatted however I don't believe that my expect (return) is correct as I'm failing to send the password.

Here's the entire routine:

```perl
sub file2SDB {
    
    my $file = $_[0];
    my $path = $_[1];
    my $type = $_[2];
    
    print "$file \n";
    print "$path \n";
    print "$type \n";
    
    
    my $prompt = 'Password:';
    my $passwd = 'xxx';
    my $cmd = "$file file-manager\@localhost\:\:$path$type";
    my $timeout=50;
    
    my $ssh_exp = new Expect();
    $ssh_exp->exp_internal(1);
    $ssh_exp->raw_pty(1);
    $ssh_exp->spawn("rsync", $cmd) or die "Cannot spawn rsync command: $!n";
    my $response = ($ssh_exp->expect($timeout, 'Password:'));
    if ($response) {
        
        $ssh_exp->send($timeout, '-re', "$passwd") or warn "Password not sent...";
    }
    else {
        print "No response from rsync command.\n";
        print "$cmd\n";
    }
    $ssh_exp->soft_close();
}
```

Comment: Can you create SSH keys? That way you wouldn't have to bother with Expect and embedding your password in your script in plain text.

Comment: Hi Brian-  I've actually done that everywhere possible.  For this case, I'm really only moving a file (not very often either) from one location to the other.  However I have to do it as a different user (file-manager); the users of the system do not have write privileges to this directory beyond using rsync.  If there's a better method, I'm all for it...:)  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry...from one location to the other and on the same box.

Comment: Couldn't you just run the rsync command without daemon (rsync local-source local-target) as file-manager? Then it requires no password at all. To do this from your script, just allow the user executing your Perl to sudo  rsync as file-manager.

Comment: Hmmm...you're likely right however I'm and Eng trying to do a Sys Admin's job in this case...:)  So, I really have no clue how to pull this off...  The command I attempted was "sudo rsync file-manager@localhost:<file> <destination>" does this sound right?